# error for querySelector() function on HTML5 data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a simple piano with all the sounds such as Do, Re, Mi etc using Vanilla Js. I am getting error regarding the querySelector function for data-* attribute. Here is the relevant part of my code.

```js
let keyArr = document.querySelectorAll(".musicKey");
var audioKeyProp;
keyArr.forEach(function(item) {
  let tempVal = item.getAttribute('data-key');
  audioKeyProp[tempVal] = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key=${tempVal}]`);
  
  //For debugging
  console.log(audioKeyProp[tempVal]);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-div">
    <div class="keys">
      <div data-key="100" class="musicKey">
        <p>D</p><span>(Do)</span></div>
      <div data-key="114" class="musicKey">
        <p>R</p><span>(Re)</span></div>
      <!--there are more such div. To make it simple I only mentioned two -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <audio data-key="100" src="audio/do.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
  <audio data-key="114" src="audio/re.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
  <!--there are more such audio elements. To make it simple I only mentioned two -->
</body>
```

I want to get the sound upon each key press.At first I want to associate each audio element with the corresponding key.

I am getting error such as,

> "soundBox.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector'
>   on 'Document': 'audio[data-key=100]' is not a valid selector."

Could you please say what am I missing ? Can't I use data-key attribute for two different elements (div and audio in my case) ? I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: You should write `let tempVal = item.dataset.key` instead of `let tempVal = item.getAttribute('data-key')` for better performance and cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap attribute value in quotes, see [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${tempVal}"]`)
```

```js
let keyArr = document.querySelectorAll(".musicKey");
var audioKeyProp;
keyArr.forEach(function(item) {

  //console.log(item);
  let tempVal = item.getAttribute('data-key');
  console.log(document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${tempVal}"]`));
});
```

```html
<div id="main-div">
  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="100" class="musicKey">
      <p>D</p><span>(Do)</span></div>
    <div data-key="114" class="musicKey">
      <p>R</p><span>(Re)</span></div>
    <!--there are more such div. To make it simple I only mentioned two -->
  </div>
</div>
<audio data-key="100" src="audio/do.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio data-key="114" src="audio/re.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks !!! it worked like a charm !!!! This one was getting on my nerve for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push this value to array it goes like this:

```
let keyArr = document.querySelectorAll(".musicKey");
let audioKeyProp = [];
keyArr.forEach(function (item) {

    console.log(item);
    let tempVal = item.getAttribute('data-key');
    audioKeyProp.push(document.querySelector(`audio[data-key='${tempVal}']`));
    console.log(audioKeyProp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll(".musicKey");
var audioKeyProp = {};
Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function (item,i) {
    let tempVal = item.getAttribute('data-key');
    let dom     = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="'+tempVal+'"]');
    if(dom)
        audioKeyProp[i] = dom.src 
});
console.log(audioKeyProp)
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-div">
    <div class="keys">
      <div data-key="100" class="musicKey"><p>D</p><span>(Do)</span></div>
      <div data-key="114" class="musicKey"><p>R</p><span>(Re)</span></div>
      <!--there are more such div. To make it simple I only mentioned two -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <audio data-key="100" src="audio/do.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
  <audio data-key="114" src="audio/re.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
 </body>
```

Comment: You have use Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodelist,function(){}) for node list forEach ..it will accept all the browser....
if You  are  using values in querySeletor do :document.querySelector('audio[data-key="'+tempVal+'"]')